# Передать id из popup в script_content

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chrome-extension

создаю расширение для google chrome.

Есть popup.html, где при первом запуске пользователь входит в свой аккаунт, к нему подключён файл auth.js, откуда идёт запрос на сайт и если всё ок - отдаёт данные. Эти данные я заношу в куки и потом уже вставляю обратно в popup.html

В принципе, всё работает, правда, есть одно **но**. В расширении так же есть end.js, который выполняется на каждой странице, так всё просто. Посылается GET запрос и принимает ответ. И вот тут есть проблемка, в этом запросе должен присутствовать id пользователя, однако он хранится в куках самого расширения и не отображается в

```
document.cookie
```

Сначала думал использовать chrome.runtime. Т.е. при авторизации пользователя заносить не только в куки, а ещё отправлять данные в end.js. А тут уже есть 2 **НО**:

1) Толком даже не получилось просто передать сообщение.

2) Если я его передам, **где его хранить?** Ведь скрипт запускается на каждом сайте и прекращает работу как вкладку закрыть. Будет ли id доступен, допустим, при повторном запуске скрипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранить юзер_данные, что он валидный, можно [тут](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage): `chrome.storage.local.get\set();`, и уже вызывать откуда хочешь - `get('user');`

Либо, можешь [использовать](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` к бг, а уже с бг отдавать ид, который ты можешь и уже положил в `localStorage.userId = '123';`. Локал сторага будет воркать по всем локальным(*chrome://ext_key*) скриптам расширения (end.js - у тебя контент скрипт[как я понял], на нём - локалсторага будет равна сайту, к которому ендец подключился)